# Pass drop-down list values from view to controller

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I have a select tag with several options and each of the options are designated a value.

```
<select id="dropdown">
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="3">Option 3</option>
    <option value="4">Option 4</option>
</select>
```

Additionally, I have the following JQuery script.

```
$(function() {
    $(#dropdown).change(function() {
        var option = $(this).find("option:selected").text();
        var optionValue = $(this).val();
```

I've checked both values using an 'alert' and they're correct. Now I want to pass these values from the view to the controller. I put the select tag within a form and tried using '.submit()' on both values, but that causes the script to crash. I'm not sure if I'm using '.submit()' correctly, as I'm a beginner in JavaScript and Jquery. So in short, how can I get the option tag value into a method of my controller?

**EDIT 1**

The select tags are in a form, and I've been trying to submit like this:

```
$(this).val().submit()
```

**EDIT 2**

Additionally, here is the controller method I'm trying to get the value into.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(string dropdown)
{
    string value = dropdown; 

    //--- conditional logic ---

    return View()
}
```

Comment: Could you show the code where you do the .submit()?

Comment: use `form` to submit the value or as you are using jQuery then you might like to use `jQuery.ajax()` to send the values to the controller.

Comment: You don't need to select the selected option through Javascript. If you add a name to the select element, and a submit button to your form, MVC will look after it for you. Easiest would be to create a model that contains a string property with the same name as your select element. If you want to use validation on the select element, I would recommend using DataAnnotations through the model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use `submit()` your dropdown must be in a `<form>`

```
<form method="POST" action="yourControllerUrl/MyAction">
    <select id="dropdown" name="dropdownName">
        <option value="1">Option 1</option>
        <option value="2">Option 2</option>
        <option value="3">Option 3</option>
        <option value="4">Option 4</option>
     </select> 
</form>
```

And in the controller :

```
public ActionResult MyAction(string dropdownName)
{        
      // use your dropdown value here 
}
```

Comment: so, does this need submit button or it will be done automatically?

Comment: if you call `submit()` explicitely you dont need a submit button

Comment: I have it in a form (@using (Html.BeginForm("Action", "Controller", FormMethod.Post) {...}).

Comment: Can you dump the relevant controller code in your question ? Moreover to call submit you cant use `$(this).val().submit()` you must call submit on the form `$("#myFormId").submit()`

Comment: Thank you so much @Quentin Roger! I was using submit incorrectly because I didn't realize I had to submit the entire form instead of specific values.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ajax to do this kind of task

```
var dropDownVal = $("#dropdown").val();
$(#dropdown).change(function() {

     $.ajax({
        url : yourControllerUrl/MyAction,
        type: "POST",
        data : {
          dropDown : dropDownVal
        }
     });

});
```

In controller use params and get the value with "dropDown" as key

Answer (score 0):

Best way would be to expand on this.... :) hope it helps.

**Model**

```
public class Model
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Items> items { get; set; } 
}
```

**View**

```
@model App.Models.Model

@using (Html.BeginForm("ActionName", "ControllerName")) {

   @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Id, Model.Items)

   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info"><i class="fa fa-floppy-o"></i></button>
}
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult ActionName(Model model)
{
   var blah = model.items;

   return View(model);
}
```

Comment: I am also doing the similar thing...Tried both via ViewBag and as you shown above but in both ways I am getting null list of values. What could be the issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75284606 ?