# Unable to send Model Data from Controller's GET Method to Controller's POST Method via View

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, http-post, viewbag

I am sending the list of affiliates from the get method of controller to View via ViewBag(ViewBag.AffiliateData) and expecting to get the same list in controller's HTTP Post Method(myAffiliateList) but receiving value as null. Could you please help me to understand what am I doing wrong here?

> **NOTE:** I am sending the data as hidden because it is not needed to be shown. So I am trying to get 2 values in HTTP-Post method, one
> which is being selected and other the whole list that is being used to
> populate the select box dynamically.

**Model:**

```
public class ModelOld
{
    public string Aname { get; set; }
    public string Acode { get; set; }
}

public class ModelNew
{
    public string Acode { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<ModelOld> myAffiliateList { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller: UserInvitation.cs**

```
// GET Method
public ActionResult Import()
{

    List<ModelOld> affiliateList = new List<ModelOld>();
    ModelNew affiliateList1 = new ModelNew();
    var affiliateMappingList = Configuration.GetSection("AffiliateMapping").GetChildren();
    foreach (var KeyValuePair in affiliateMappingList)
    {
        affiliateList.Add(new ModelOld()
        {
            Aname = KeyValuePair.Key,
            Acode = KeyValuePair.Value
        });
    }
    affiliateList.Insert(0, new ModelOld { Acode = "", Aname = "--Select Your Affiliate--" });
    affiliateList1.myAffiliateList = affiliateList;
    ViewBag.AffiliateData = affiliateList1.myAffiliateList;
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> ImportAsync(string Acode, IEnumerable<ModelOld> myAffiliateList)
{
    //Some Code
}
```

**View: Import.cshtml**

```
@model ModelNew
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Import", "UserInvitation", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-10">
                <label class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-2" title="Select Your Affiliate" style="font-size:large;"><b>Affiliate:</b></label>
                <select id="affiliate" class="form-control" style="-webkit-appearance:listbox" asp-for="Acode" asp-items="@(new SelectList(ViewBag.AffiliateData,"Acode","Aname"))">
                </select>
                
                @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.myAffiliateList, htmlAttributes: new { @Value = ViewBag.AffiliateData })
                
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-10">
                <br />
                <button type="submit" id="btnSubmitData" title="Click to Invite the Users" class="btn btn-info">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></i> Invite Users
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You aren't showing enough code.  For instance, where are you calling ImportAsync?  I don't see any URL routing to that method or any HTTP client invoking a web method.

Comment: @rory.ap Import is being called via "using (Html.BeginForm..." statement in View.cshtml, post clicking the submit button.

Comment: Hi @Lucifer, what is your `AffiliateModel`? Is it same as the `ModelNew` model? And it is impossible to post the complex model by simple input element. You need set all the model's property to the hidden input then it can be posted and bound to the backend. But for your scenario, you set the Tempdata in the get method, you can get the Tempdata in your post method instead of model binding the model.

Comment: @Rena AffiliateModel and ModelOld is same in my context. Actually I removed the AffiliateModel now and made ModelOld everywhere. Will update it in my question as well, to avoid the confusion.

Comment: Hi @Lucifer, if the two model are the same, just try my answer below, any problem for my answer after trying?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a whole working demo:

Model

```
public class ModelOld
{
    public string Aname { get; set; }
    public string Acode { get; set; }
}   
public class AffiliateModel
{
    public string Aname { get; set; }
    public string Acode { get; set; }
}

public class ModelNew
{
    public string Acode { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<ModelOld> myAffiliateList { get; set; }
}
```

View

```
@model ModelNew
@{
    var data = TempData["AffiliateData"] as string;
    TempData.Keep("AffiliateData");   //be sure add this to persist the data....
    var list = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<IEnumerable<ModelOld>>(data);
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Import", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {
        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-10">
                    <label class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-2" title="Select Your Affiliate" style="font-size:large;"><b>Affiliate:</b></label>
                    <select id="affiliate" class="form-control" style="-webkit-appearance:listbox" asp-for="Acode" 
           asp-items="@(new SelectList(list,"Acode","Aname"))">   @*change here....*@
                    </select>
        
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br />
        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-10">
                    <br />
                    <button type="submit" id="btnSubmitData" title="Click to Invite the Users" class="btn btn-info">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></i> Invite Users
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
</body>
</html>
```

Controller

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    List<ModelOld> affiliateList = new List<ModelOld>();
    ModelNew affiliateList1 = new ModelNew();
    var affiliateMappingList = Configuration.GetSection("AffiliateMapping").GetChildren();
    foreach (var KeyValuePair in affiliateMappingList)
    {
        affiliateList.Add(new ModelOld()
        {
            Aname = KeyValuePair.Key,
            Acode = KeyValuePair.Value
        });
    }
    affiliateList.Insert(0, new ModelOld { Acode = "", Aname = "--Select Your Affiliate--" });
    affiliateList1.myAffiliateList = affiliateList;

    //change here....
    //or asp.net core 2.x,you could use NewtonSoft.Json -----JsonConvert.SerializeObject(affiliateList1.myAffiliateList);

    TempData["AffiliateData"] = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(affiliateList1.myAffiliateList);


    return View();
}
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> ImportAsync(string Acode)
{
    var data = TempData["AffiliateData"] as string;
    IEnumerable<AffiliateModel> myAffiliateList = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<IEnumerable<AffiliateModel>>(data);
    return View();
}
```

Comment: May I ask why are we using 2 models(ModelOld and AffiliateModel) with same properties?

Comment: Hi @Lucifer,  That is because you set the viewbag with value `myAffiliateList` which is type of `IEnumerable<ModelOld>` but you want to receive `IEnumerable<AffiliateModel>`. So I think they should contain same properties. If the properties are not the same, how it binds the value to another model here?

Comment: Then, for my posted answer here,  you can use `AffiliateModel` with different properties, just deserialize the TempData to `IEnumerable<ModelOld>`. And foreach the model to set the corresponding value to the `IEnumerable<AffiliateModel>`.

Comment: Also, I have asked you for the `AffiliateModel` in my first comment previously.

Comment: I tried your solution but facing one issue that when I select an option from the dropdown, submit and suppose some error came due to negative scenario, the page reloads but the selected option remains in place rather than resetting the dropdown list selection. Can we reset it somehow?

Comment: Hi @Lucifer, you mean you want to reset the dropdown list when post back, right? Just add `ModelState.Clear();` before return View in the `ImportAsync` method.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Rena for helping with the issue here. Everything works now as expected. I have marked the Answer as Accepted.